# Implementing CCAvenue in React Native

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am implementing CCAvenue payment gateway in React Native.

*React Native version 0.60.4*

I have created an WebView, passing an HTML source file. In which I am  hitting the end point of CCAvenue with required data using AJAX. On receiving the response I am sending the HTML response from CCAvenue to Native end.

**Payment.js**

````
```
import React, { useSate, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

var crypto = require('crypto')
var qs = require('qs')

const encrypt = (plainText, workingKey) => {
  var m = crypto.createHash('md5')
  m.update(workingKey)
  var key = m.digest()
  var iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv)
  var encoded = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex')
  encoded += cipher.final('hex')
  return encoded
}
const data = {
  merchant_id: 'MERCHANT ID',
  order_id: '1232321',
  amount: '1.00'
  currency: 'INR',
  language: 'EN',
  redirect_url: 'redirect address',
  cancel_url: 'cancel address'
}


function Payment(props) {
  const [HTML, setHTML] = useState('')
  const webviewRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // have to put it inside a timeout function, otherwise the postMessage was called before the page was loaded
    setTimeout(() => {
      const body = qs.stringify(data),
      const workingKey = 'WORKING_KEY,
      const accessCode = 'ACCESS_CODE',
      const encRequest = encrypt(body, workingKey)

      const formbody = '<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"/> <input type="hidden" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="' + encRequest + '"><input type="hidden" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="' + accessCode + '"><script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script></form>'

      webviewRef.current.postMessage(JSON.stringify(formbody))
    }, 200)
  }, [webviewRef])

  const _onWebViewMessage = message => {
    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.nativeEvent.data)
    setHTML(parsedMessage.result)
  }

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={ref => (webviewRef.current = ref)}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={HTML.length ? { html: HTML } : { uri: 'file:///android_asset/widget/ccavenue.html' }}
      domStorageEnabled
      javaScriptEnabled
      allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
      onMessage={message => _onWebViewMessage(message)}
      onError={e => console.log('Webview Error', e)}
      mixedContentMode='always'
    />
  )
}
=============================
````

Our backend team have done this in Node js

**ccavRequestHandler.js**

```
var http = require("http"),
  qs = require("querystring");

exports.postReq = function(request, response) {
  var body = qs.stringify(request.body),
    workingKey = 'WORKING_KEY',
    accessCode = 'ACCESS_CODE',
    encRequest = encrypt(body, workingKey),
    formbody = "";

  var request = require("request");

  request(
    "https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"
  )
    .on("data", function(data) {
      formbody =
        '<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"/> <input type="hidden" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="' +
        encRequest +
        '"><input type="hidden" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="' +
        accessCode +
        '"><script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script></form>';
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.write(formbody);
      response.end();
    });

  return;
};
```

In React Native I am getting this error after sending the POST request with mentioned formbody

> Error Code: 10001     Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not
>   present.
>
> Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.

Whereas on hitting the ccavRequestHandler.js from Node.js, we are getting the correct response from CCAvenue, which is an HTML.

How can I do something similar like request.on using AJAX. I think I am missing something in that section.

Comment: I have similar issue, E10002 Merchant Authentication failed. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: @MahendraThotakura You are getting Authentication failed, thats a complete different error to what I actually posted back then. Please check your test card credentials.

Comment: can anyone provide documentation to implement ccavenue in react native

Comment: @Vishali This is one of the document I followed earlier to have an idea https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAvenue_Integration%20_Ver_3_1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

CCAvenue Request doesn't work that way. It should have a valid Referrer (ie. IP/Domain) through which the Gateway has been configured. Request made through ccavRequestHandler.js from node.js worked, coz the request has a valid IP/Domain with which your ccAvenue account is being configured.

To make the same process work in mobile (ie. react native) create a page in server which receives your input through WebView and made prepare a post request from that page with all the required form parameters linking to ccAvenue Gateway and everything should be work fine.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Requesting via form worked for me


`<form
    method="post"
    id="redirect"
    name="redirect"
    action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"
>
    <input id="encRequest" type="text" name="encRequest" hidden />
    <input id="access_code" type="text" name="access_code" hidden />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" hidden />
</form>`

Comment: Can you please tell me how do i create a page in server for this 
Please

Comment: @BiplovKumar check the SDK file provided with your ccAvenue or you can download by login into their portal which has all required files and functions to put in your server.

Comment: @DineshRavichandran could you please help me to integrate ccavenue for react native application

Comment: @DineshRavichandran please provide any documentation or github link to follow

Comment: it will be very useful for the users like me